# ASP.NET MVC 4 controller inheritance

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, controller, http-status-code-404

I have the following setup:
**BaseController1** inherits ***System.Web.Mvc.Controller***. This controller is compiled into a separate dll that is referenced from my project.
**BaseController2** inherits **BaseController1** in my project.
**MyController** inherits **BaseController2**.
When I run application with this setup, I get 404 error.
But if **BaseController2** inherits directly ***System.Web.Mvc.Controller***, and I run application with this setup, everything works as expected.
I have default constructor for all inherited controllers with : base() called.
The **BaseController1** within assembly is compiled using references to asp.net mvc 3, and my project relies completely on asp.net mvc 4.
Can this be the problem? Or I am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you debug through it, what's the actual error that's generating the 404? Do you have a stack trace or exception occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong, but you will have to make MVC look in the specific assembly/namespace:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add(
    "ExternalAssembly.Controllers");
```

This has already been answered in this question: [asp.net mvc put controllers into a separate project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401376/asp-net-mvc-put-controllers-into-a-separate-project)

Comment: You pointerd me in right direction. The solution was to set 'Specific Version' to false under properties for System.web.mvc dll in Visual Studio. Thanks!