# Multiple MVC projects in a single solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have seen in NopCommerce project that there is a solution and there are multiple MVC projects within the solution.

I have some questions about it such as :

How is it possible to share a main layout, or use different layout on demand?
How is it possible to use Controllers/Models etc. in different MVC projects?

I would also like one main project and multiple sub MVC projects. How can this be done while sharing components?

Any ideas? pointers?

Note: Not interested in Areas.

Comment: Why are you not interested in Areas. What do you want to achieve that you can't with Areas?

Comment: because of the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is. See: [asp.net mvc put controllers into a separate project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401376/asp-net-mvc-put-controllers-into-a-separate-project)

I've done this myself and was able to use the controllers in a plug-in type architecture.

As for the models, they are just normal classes. They can be used in any project for any reason. There is nothing special about them.