# Is it possible to wrap a controller in a seperate dll and integrate it into another MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, components

I want to wrap some authentication logic in a controller, and re-use it in a few other MVC projects.

Is it possible to wrap the controller logic and drop the .dll in the other projects?

How will I re-write the routing logic for this?

Would using 'Areas' make this more or less complicated?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401376/asp-net-mvc-put-controllers-into-a-separate-project

That's all you need to do.