# How does the MVC framework know which controller to use when controllers are in a separate class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just created an MVC project using the .NET 4.5 framework with  controllers in a separate class library.

I had previously thought that if the controllers are in separate class library you need to create a custom controller factory as discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401376/asp-net-mvc-put-controllers-into-a-separate-project).  However, my controllers are being instantiated and are working fine without having to do this.

How does the framework (the newer ones at least) know to use the controllers in the separate class libary without being *told* to do so?  All I needed to do was add a reference to the controllers project.

Comment: They all inherit from the same class which is known to the MVC framework. All they have to do is to find all types that extend that class.

Comment: Just to add a little to @MarcelN.'s comment, the routing framework uses reflection to load in controller-type classes (it's actually anything that implements `IController`). What assembly it comes from is irrelevant. It then looks for matches on any of these "controllers" to the route that was hit.

Comment: So having to create a custom controller factory was never necessary, or has this controller 'auto-detection' been added to newer releases of MVC?

Comment: I also thought default ControllerFactory only knows how to instantiate parameterless controller constructors, but I'm using DI using constructor injection and it's all working fine.

Comment: A customer controller factory was never necessary for this aspect of the framework. It's necessary for other scenarios such as DI. And, if you're using a DI container with your controllers you've got a custom factory, you just may not be aware of it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - not true, MVC has, since version 3 had DI support built in with IDependencyResolver that DI frameworks can hook into so no custom factory is required.

Comment: @MarkErasmus - no, as long as the assembly is referenced by your primary assembly, then MVC can find the controller.  MVC can also create use constructors with a single constructor that has parameters if something has hooked into the IDependencyResolver hook to do DI (such as NinjectDependencyResolver, WindsorDependencyResolver, UnityDependencyResolver, etc..)  You can still do the custom factory route if you wish, but most frameworks will now auto-install the resolver if you use the nuget package to install it.