# How to @HTML.ActionLink to a controller/view in another dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dllimport, class-library

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution which references to another class library, in which i have an MVC folder and inside of it "Controller", "Model" and "View" folders. I'd like to do something like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Index", "DllController")
```

which will link to the DllController/Index action in the dll and show a view from that lib. Debugging through this, I see that it goes into the Controller, but once it reaches

```
return View("MyView", model);
```

I receive the foolowing error:

> The view 'MyView' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/MyView/MyView.aspx
>   ~/Views/MyView/MyView.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/MyView.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/MyView.ascx
>   ~/Views/MyView/MyView.cshtml
>   ~/Views/MyView/MyView.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/MyView.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/MyView.vbhtml
>   ~/Mvc/Views/MyView/MyView.cshtml
>   ~/Mvc/Views/Shared/MyView.cshtml

I assume this is because the view is being searched for in the current assembly. Can i change this behavior to show my imported view correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc put controllers into a separate project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401376/asp-net-mvc-put-controllers-into-a-separate-project)

Comment: Not exactly as my issue is with showing the view, not accessing the controller.